# Thoughtworks GO - Changing Artefact File Permissions

Tags: thoughtworks-go

I'm using thoughworks go for a build pipeline as shown below:

[image]

The "Test" stage fetches artefacts from the build stage and runs each of it's jobs in parallel (unit tests, integration test, acceptance tests, package) on different ages. However, each of those jobs is a shell script.

When those tasks are run on a different agent they are failing because permission is denied. Each job is a shell script, and when I ssh into the agent I can see it does not have executable permissions as shown below:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 go go 4096 Mar  4 09:48 .
drwxrwxr-x 8 go go 4096 Mar  4 09:48 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 go go  408 Mar  4 09:48 aa_tests.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 go go  443 Mar  4 09:48 Dockerfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 go go  121 Mar  4 09:48 run.sh
```

However, in the git repository they have executable permission and they seem to execute fine on the build agent that clones the git repository.

Comment: See also https://github.com/gocd/gocd/issues/464

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by executing the script with bash. E.g "bash sriptname.sh" as the command for the task.

Comment: Any idea how to run test binaries? `./tests` does not work because of the described permission problem.

Comment: for me command `/bin/bash` and argument 
```-c
bash scriptname.sh scriptargument```
worked